# GhostScript does not print PDF file to a real printer correctly, but works fine with PDFCreator

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, ghostscript, pdfsharp

I'm trying to print a PDF file using GhostScript, with the following switches along with a valid input file path:
`-dPrinted -dNOPAUSE -dNoCancel -dNOPROMPT -dNOSAFER -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sOutputFile=%printer%printerName`

If I use PDFCreator, it works fine and gives another output pdf file. But when I use a real printer, the image is all messed up.

This is the file I'm trying to print:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByL_VDOdxc3MbmpocEo0Vnhhd2c/view?usp=sharing
This is the scan of what came out of the printer:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_KRzl3VVurjaTVIbkhkaUc0Y1E/view?usp=sharing

The PDF file I'm trying to print is rendered by PDFSharp.
I am using `GS version 9.15 32-bit` on `Windows 8` and the real printer I'm using is `Brother Printer, model MFC-7840W`.
Also when I try to print generic sample PDFs I find on Google to the real printer, it works fine.

Does anyone know what is causing this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The most obvious problem is that the width of the image is messed up badly, could be that the resolution is wrong I guess. Though I'm baffled by the information that it works with other PDF files. The way the mswinpr2 device works, it renders the PDF file to a bitmap, which it then draws on a printer DeviceContext. It then tells the device context to print itself to the printer. Its really hard to see how the same process can work with a 'PDFCreator' and with other files, but not this one specific file on the printer.

Comment: By the way, the PDF file doesn't embed the font 3of9Barcode and so Ghostscript substitutes it with Helvetica (the same happens with other viewers, Acrobat substitutes bullets instead). This results in some text appearing "*100017*" where there ought, I suspect, to be a bar code. Oh, and it doesn't include MicrosoftSansSerif either.

Comment: The only odd thing I can see about your file is that it contains a Transparency Group over the entire page, you *could* try removing that (it seems to serve no useful purpose). But the fact that other files work on the printer, and this file works to other printers, puzzles me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be an issue with the soft mask of the PDF file itself. This issue has been resolved in version 9.16 of GhostScript.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues has just reminded me that we ran across what 'might' be a related problem a few months back and suggested a workaround whic, I believe, resolved the problem in that case.

The mswinpr2 device includes a comment:

```
/* This driver uses the printer default size and resolution and
 * ignores page size and resolution set using -gWIDTHxHEIGHT and
 * -rXxY.  You must still set the correct PageSize to get the
 * correct clipping path.
 * The code in win_pr2_getdc() does try to set the printer page
 * size from the PostScript PageSize, but it isn't working
 * reliably at the moment.
 *
 * This driver doesn't work with some Windows printer drivers.
 * The reason is unknown.  All printers to which I have access
 * work.
 *
 * rjl 1997-11-20
 */
```

The important point is that you must set the PageSize (to get the clip correct) and also use the -g switch to set the width and height of the image (in pixels) and set the resolution correctly for the printer using -r. This might need some experimentation.....

You could also consider using gsprint, which is part of the current GSView. That has an updated version of the printing method (by the same author) which is claimed to be an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for all your time and effort Ken. I have been playing around with it a bit more and just discovered that if the logo image on the top right is removed, the whole PDF file prints fine, even to the real printer.

Comment: That is definitely weird, offhand I'm unable to think of any reason for that. The only thing we could do is offer to stick some debugging into the Ghostscript mswinpr2 device to try and figure out what's different between working and non-working cases. If you want to go down that route, then its probably best to come see us on IRC (I know one of your colleagues came by today) and we can chat about it there. Best time for us is UK office hours though there are often people on at all kinds of strange times.